Consteval error: taking address of an immediate function
I was solving https://projecteuler.net/problem=206, and wanted a compile time (consteval) solution.
My idea was to check every number, until the answer is found. However, my code does not compile.
Here is my code:
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <print>
#include <ranges>

using namespace std;

consteval auto check_if_square_has_special_form(int x) -> bool
{
    long long square = 1LL * x * x;

    for (const int digit : {0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1})
    {
        const bool last_digit_is_correct = (square % 10) == digit;
        
        if (!last_digit_is_correct)
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        square /= 100;
    }

    return true;
}

auto concealed_square() -> int
{
    const auto positive_numbers = views::iota(1); // Goes on to infinity.
    const int answer = *ranges::find_if(positive_numbers, check_if_square_has_special_form);

    return answer;
}

auto main() -> int
{
    println("The answer is {}", concealed_square());

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

This fails to compile, and outputs:
error: taking address of an immediate function 'consteval bool check_if_square_has_special_form(int)'.
Why do I get this error, and how to circumvent it? Using a regular for loop also doesn't seem to work.

std::find_if is called at runtime, why do you think it can call a compile time only function?

Isn't the point of consteval to get a value at compile time... So even if this worked it would provide you with no benefit, since positive_numbers is not generated at compile time..

But even if instead of using views::iota and std::find_if I use a regular for-loop, it still doesn't compile.

You can make check_if_square_has_special_form constexpr instead of consteval.

Theoretically you could make concealed_square consteval as well, but I doubt any compiler will do such heavy compile time calculation (MSVC fails - "failure was caused by evaluation exceeding step limit of 1048576 (/constexpr:steps)").

std::initializer_list can not be constexpr. Use std::array  instead: std::array{0, 9, 8}.

@wohlstad gcc outright refuses to run this at compile time. If the problem was caused by exceeding evaluation limit, I think there is a special flag to solve it.

consteval makes very little sense there. You need to run the code once.

@n.m.couldbeanAI I agree, but half the point of solving such problems is learning, so it is still interesting to understand the root of the issue.

auto main() -> int Its cute how AAA still survives in some code :D

@PlsHelp if you want to learn the proper usage of consteval you should use a calculation which is feasible for the compiler to perform at compile time.

@wohlstad If you replace the code of check_if_square_has_special_form by a simple return true; it still outputs the same error. So the issue is elsewhere.

This is how I compile (after making concealed_square conseval too):  g++ -o eu eu.cpp -std=c++23 -fconstexpr-ops-limit=10000000000 -fconstexpr-loop-limit=2147483647 and it gets killed by the OOM reaper after 7 minutes or so. Default values for the flags lead to a "constexpr limit exceeded" error.

@PlsHelp if I change check_if_square_has_special_form to return true (and make concealed_square also consteval in order to use it) - it works. See demo.

@wohlstad Thanks! Seems that after all the true mistake was not declaringconcealed_square as consteval.

Alternatively, you can mark positive_numbers and answers as constexpr https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40755d52c7ca2009
